# Extension of valuations and completion

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, fields, p-adic

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of fields where $K$ is a number field. Let $v$ be a valuation of $K$ and denotes by $K_v$ its completion for this valuation. One denotes $\tilde v$ be the valuation $K_v$. Let $v_1,\cdots,v_s$ be the extensions of $v$ to $L$. Assume that $L_{v_i}\simeq K_v$ for every $i$. For $a\in L$, can one explicit $\tilde v(a)$ in function of the $v_i$'s?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to specify *how* $L$ is embedded in $K_v$. Let $K=\mathbf Q$, $L = \mathbf Q(i)$, $v=5$-adic valuation on $\mathbf Q$. The two  extensions of $v$ to $L$ are the valuations on $L$ associated to  $1+2i$ and $1-2i$. The number $\widetilde{v}(1+2i)$ is not meaningful  without specifying which square root of $-1$ in $\mathbf Q_5$ is meant  by $i$, which amounts to saying how $L$ is embedded in $\mathbf Q_5$.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the problem.